# VIM: how to stay in visual mode after fixing indentation with ==

Tags: vim

I want the following steps:

- select C code in visual mode
- do proper indentation with ==
- select the same code again using gv
- now align the code with \tsp (Dr chip's Align Plugin).

I am trying to map all the steps to a single key

```
vmap a ==gv\tsp
```

But this is not working properly. == is executed properly but not gv and \tsp .
I have also tried

```
vmap a ==gv
```

It seems that gv is not working after executing == . The visual selection is not retained after == .

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In visual mode you use `=` to indent the selection (since you can't specify a motion, `==` would just be redundant).

`vmap a =gv\tsp` will work.

The extra `=` actually causes your map to fail, as it first indents (the first `=`), then (now back in normal mode), the second `=` waits for a motion (which `gv` is not).

Comment: works like a charm .. how did I miss that .. thanks.